# Making static library in VS10: How to include whole directory

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, dll, compilation

I am making static library for the first time and I need to input all .h dependencies in stdafx.h, however there are so many that I have to ask if there is some command to instead inputting every single h file individually, include whole directory at once, something like shown below:

```
#include "lib\behaviors\ *"
#include "lib\automaticProcessing\ *"
```

Thanks on your feedback.

P.S. I forgot to mention that I know for "making a giant" technique, where you put all dependencies in one .h file, and then include only that .h where is needed( like in this occasion ) but I forgot to apply that technique while I was building my library, so I am stuck now without that help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`dir *.h > all_headers.h` followed by a little editing of the output. Then just `#include "all_headers.h"` in each of your sources. There isn't any wildcard you can apply to #include.

Comment: I'd probably do something like `for /r %i in (*.h) do echo #include "%i" >> file.h` and then chop off the front of each line to make the paths relative to where they need to be, but same general idea.